# React navigate router dom is not working when am trying to work on the react redux JWT auth for privateroute

Tags: reactjs, redux

There are some issue when am trying to use private router for react redux JWT auth in the project. When am trying to access the dashboard am not seeing the output with the below code.

```html
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import TopNav from "./components/TopNav";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/PrivateRoute";
// components
import Home from "./booking/Home";
import Login from "./auth/Login";
import Register from "./auth/Register";
import Dashboard from "./user/Dashboard";
import DashboardSeller from "./user/DashboardSeller";
import NewHotel from "./hotels/NewHotel";
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <TopNav />
      <ToastContainer position="top-center" />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
          <Route element={<Dashboard />} path="/dashboard" />
          <Route element={<DashboardSeller />} path="/dashboard/seller" />
          <Route element={<NewHotel />} path="/hotels/new" />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  let auth = { token: true };
  return auth.token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question? If so, you need to explain it...